# How does DPAPI protect the master key for a service account?

Tags: windows, sql-server

I am trying to understand the security of [TDE for MSSQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2017). The documentation says it relies on [Windows DPAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). DPAPI generates a master key using a user's credentials. This works well for human users where the password is never stored on the machine.

I do not understand how DPAPI works when generating master keys for service accounts (either MSA's or the built-in service accounts) where I understand the password to be stored in the registry.

How does TDE protect the data if it relies on a master key that relies on a service account password which is stored in the same device as the data?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you might try Database Administrators (where you're more likely to find someone who has used TDE) or perhaps Information Security.  For what it's worth, a quick look at the documentation suggests to me that TDE does not and is not intended to protect against the entire server (operating system and all) being stolen, only against theft of the database files.  In many scenarios that may be sufficient to meet regulatory requirements, and perhaps even to significantly reduce the actual risk - e.g., backups are often easier to steal than servers.